# Mysql Partitioning Query Performance

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.7

i have created partitions on pricing table. below is the alter statement.

```
ALTER TABLE `price_tbl` 
PARTITION BY HASH(man_code)
PARTITIONS 87;
```

one partition consists of 435510 records. total records in price_tbl is 6 million.

EXPLAIN query showing only one partion is used for the query . Still the query takes **3-4 sec** to execute. below is the query

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT vrimg.image_cap_id,vm.man_name,vr.range_code,vr.range_name,vr.range_url, MIN(`finance_rental`) AS from_price, vd.der_id AS vehicle_id FROM `range_tbl` vr 
    LEFT JOIN `image_tbl` vrimg ON vr.man_code = vrimg.man_code AND vr.type_id = vrimg.type_id AND vr.range_code = vrimg.range_code 
    LEFT JOIN `manufacturer_tbl` vm ON vr.man_code = vm.man_code AND vr.type_id = vm.type_id 
    LEFT JOIN `derivative_tbl` vd ON vd.man_code=vm.man_code AND vd.type_id = vr.type_id AND vd.range_code=vr.range_code 
    LEFT JOIN `price_tbl` vp ON vp.vehicle_id = vd.der_id AND vd.type_id = vp.type_id AND vp.product_type_id=1 AND vp.maintenance_flag='N'  AND vp.man_code=164 
    AND vp.initial_rentals_id =(SELECT rental_id FROM `rentals_tbl` WHERE rental_months='9') 
    AND vp.annual_mileage_id =(SELECT annual_mileage_id FROM `mileage_tbl` WHERE annual_mileage='8000') 
    WHERE vr.type_id = 1 AND vm.man_url = 'audi' AND vd.type_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY vd.der_id
```

Result of EXPLAIN.

[image]

Same query without partitioning takes 3-4 sec.
Query with partitioning takes 2-3 sec.

how we can increase query performance as it is too slow yet.

**attached create table structure.**

1. price table - This consists 6 million records

```
CREATE TABLE `price_tbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lender_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initial_rentals_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `term_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `annual_mileage_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maintenance_flag` enum('Y','N') DEFAULT NULL,
  `finance_rental` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthly_rental` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maintenance_payment` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initial_payment` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_fee` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`type_id`,`man_code`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`),
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`),
  KEY `product_type_id` (`product_type_id`),
  KEY `finance_rental` (`finance_rental`),
  KEY `type_id_2` (`type_id`,`vehicle_id`),
  KEY `maintenanace_idx` (`maintenance_flag`),
  KEY `lender_idx` (`lender_id`),
  KEY `initial_idx` (`initial_rentals_id`),
  KEY `man_code_idx` (`man_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5830708 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (man_code)
PARTITIONS 87 */
```

2. derivative table - This consists 18k records.

```
CREATE TABLE `derivative_tbl` (
  `type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_cap_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_style_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_intro_year` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_disc_year` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_last_spec_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `der_id` (`der_id`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `man_code` (`man_code`),
  KEY `range_code` (`range_code`),
  KEY `model_code` (`model_code`),
  KEY `body_idx` (`body_style_id`),
  KEY `capcodeidx` (`der_cap_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

3. range table - This consists 1k records

```
CREATE TABLE `range_tbl` (
  `type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `man_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_code` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `range_code` (`range_code`),
  KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `man_code` (`man_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: You should be worring more about the correctnesss of your query as that is not generally speaking how to use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)  .. Well MySQL 5.7.5+ with enabled sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY can be trusted with this query as detection of functional dependence is supported there which you are trusting on here..  .. Assuming the query is functional dependent i didn't check...

Comment: partitioning isn't a sllver bullet for performance gain (jet) which might change in the future as the MySQL Dev team seams to be working on [Parallel Query Execution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_parallel_read_threads) support on the InnoDB engine..  There is also a other article [MySQL 8.0.14: A Road to Parallel Query Execution is Wide Open!](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/) which indeed shows it is still pretty limited but it is a start right, we waited long on this?..

Comment: ... also from the looks into the query and explain i am pretty sure a SQL rewite is the best option to get better performance as the optimizer seams to be accesing the tables in the "wrong" order to prevent the temporary table and sort..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide example data and expected results so we can verify the SQL rewrite..  Also do a `SHOW VERSION()` as the MySQL optimizers can be very differenet between major MySQL versions..

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post ALL the CREATE tables used in the query?

Answer (score 1):

`PARTITION BY HASH` is essentially useless if you are hoping for improved performance.  `BY RANGE` is useful in a *few* use cases_.

In *most* situations, improvements in indexes are as good as trying to use partitioning.

Some likely problems:

- No explicit `PRIMARY KEY` for InnoDB tables.  Add a natural PK, if applicable, else an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- No "composite" indexes -- they often provide a performance boost.  Example:  The `LEFT JOIN` between `vr` and `vrimg` involves 3 columns; a composite index on those 3 columns in the 'right' table will probably help performance.
- Blind use of `BIGINT` when smaller datatypes would work.  (This is an I/O issue when the table is big.)
- Blind use of 255 in `VARCHAR`.
- Consider whether most of the columns should be `NOT NULL`.
- That query may be a victim of the "explode-implode" syndrome.  This is where you do `JOIN(s)`, which create a big intermediate table, followed by a `GROUP BY` to bring the row-count back down.
- Don't use `LEFT` unless the 'right' table really is optional.  (I see `LEFT JOIN vd ... vd.type_id IS NOT NULL`.)
- Don't normalize "continuous" values (annual_mileage and rental_months).  It is not really beneficial for "=" tests, and it severely hurts performance for "range" tests.

> Same query without partitioning takes 3-4 sec. Query with partitioning takes 2-3 sec.

The indexes almost always need changing when switching between partitioning and non-partitioning.  With the optimal indexes *for each case*, I predict that performance will be close to the same.

**Indexes**

These should help performance whether or not it is partitioned:

```
vm:     (man_url)
vr:     (man_code, type_id)  -- either order
vd:     (man_code, type_id, range_code, der_id)
              -- `der_id` 4th, else in any order (covering)
vrimg:  (man_code, type_id, range_code, image_cap_id)
              -- `image_cap_id` 4th, else in any order (covering)
vp:     (type_id, der_id, product_type_id, maintenance_flag,
         initial_rentals, annual_mileage, man_code)
             -- any order (covering)
```

A "covering" index is an extra boost, in that it can do all the work just in the index's BTree, without touching the data's BTree.

Implement a bunch of what I recommend, then come back (in another Question) for further tweaking.

Usually the "partition key" should be last in a composite index.